# Magento 2 - Frontend admin link

Tags: magento2

Is there a setting or a plugin for Magento 2 where I can,

1. Login to the admin
2. View pages in the frontend
3. Click on an admin link to take me to the edit the content for that page in the backend admin

Wordpress has similar functionality, when logged in to the admin a user has the option to follow an admin link in the header to edit the content of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look this extension : https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-admin-product-preview-plus-extension.html

PS: I'm not their developer / stakeholders. Just trying to help, I've searching before and this is my solution. It won't be the same as Wordpress, but it's similar (just not really in the header).

Answer (score 0):

Recently we have released the FREE extension which does exactly the same.

Feel FREE to download the extension "Magento 2 Preview/Visit Catalog" and let us know your feedback:
https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-preview-catalog-visit-sku.html